# Angular2-moment Pipe in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic3 with [angular2-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment). The pipe works perfectly to format a timestamp, e.g.:

**html**

```
<ion-note class="small-text-search">
  Last Online {{personModel.lastAccessDate | amTimeAgo:true}} ago
</ion-note>
```

outputs:

```
Last Online 19 days ago
```

This is in my **html** code. I would however like to do this in a **Javascript** string, e.x

**ts**

```
'Last Online '+personModel.lastAccessDate | amTimeAgo:true +' ago';
```

error:

```
Typescript Error Cannot find name 'amTimeAgo'.
```

**Question**

Does anyone know how to use pipes in javascript? How would I code this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most pipes are just thin wrappers around respective services.

Some pipes have functionality that is difficult to replace otherwise (e.g. builtin Angular pipes). In this case pipe class can be instantiated and `transform` method can be called.

Few pipes are designed to be used solely with compiler, like the ones that use `ChangeDetectorRef` to integrate with components. [`time-ago` pipe is one of those pipes.](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/blob/master/src/time-ago.pipe.ts#L18)

The proper way to do this is to use services and libraries directly. Incidentally, angular2-moment is a wrapper for Moment library. It should be

```
'Last Online '+ moment(personModel.lastAccessDate).fromNow() +' ago';
```

Comment: I'm still confused about why we create redundant code blocks since we have already do the same logic by building custom Pipes.  And I just searched and find this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3809.

Comment: @Pengyy Because pipe introduces overhead and can do things that aren't compatible with such way of using it (moment.fromNow vs time-ago is very good example of this). Using a service/library directly is very KISS approach. The only good reason to use `transform` is when there are no good alternatives (I did this with built-in pipes but had to check that their logic won't cause problems). It was a bit different with A1 and $filter, but in A2+ it's so.

Comment: thanks for your explaination, I just mentioned TimeAgoPipe inject `ChangeDetectRef`.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing this out now. How do I import `moment`?  I get `Cannot find name 'moment'. `.

Comment: `import * as moment from 'moment'`, I guess. If you don't have it installed apart from a2-moment package, you should install moment to the project.

Comment: I add the following: `import * as moment from 'moment'` (which does take me to `moment.d.ts`), but now get: `Property 'fromNow' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'.`

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. It does have this method. https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts#L534

Comment: I think the method signature may be incorrect. i.e it accepts a `boolean`, and not a `number`. Will check...

Comment: I am confused, not sure how to pass a time in milliseconds to `moment` and have it return `x minutes` / `y days` / etc ago (from now). I do have have the current time in millis and the time I need to calculate from.

Comment: I stand corrected, it should be `moment(...).fromNow()`. This is what TS is good for, finding human mistakes in code. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: Thank you for all your help, the solution you posted works.